# Meaning of triangle symbol

Tags: notation

I would like to use the `\blacktriangle` symbol in my latex doucument, to symbolize something. Now I am wondering, if this is a symbol that has some kind of mathematical meaning, that I am not aware of. Does the symbol mean something or is it just some random graphic?

Comment: According to [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cblacktriangle%24&p=1), that symbol hasn't been used on MSE or AoPS before. It doesn't mean _nobody_ has used it, but it probably doesn't mean anything common

Comment: Perhaps its used as a pointer...

Comment: Take into account that it will attract the eye. A handful of $\blacktriangle$ sprinkled around a page can be distracting.

Comment: won't be useful once MSE brings the dark theme :D

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge, no.

In general, I assume filled-in symbols do not appear much in written languages.